# How to create Span<T> with initial size?

Tags: c#

How can I create `Span<int>` with the initial size?

I want to achieve below points.

1. Array should be allocated on the stack and not heap(because of this I want to use `Span<T>`)
2. I know the size of the array in advance. so don't want to waste CPU reallocating and copying array around.

Comment: A span is an anonymous reference to another array. You would want to allocate an array with stackalloc then call AsSpan

Comment: oh, got it thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `stackalloc` operator array can be created on `stack` and can be assigned to Span

1. `Span<int> numbers = stackalloc int[length];`
2. `Span<int> numbers = stackalloc[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };`

attached link for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc

**edit**
This requires `C#` version 7.2 or greater